# Can Markdown be recovered from the Stack Overflow data dump?

Tags: support, markdown, data-dump

I've just got my hands on [a data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/), and I'm disappointed to see that the `Body` field of the posts is in HTML rather than Markdown. I know there's markdown in the original database, because that's what I see if I try to edit an answer.

I don't want to make life difficult for [Jeff Atwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) and his team by requesting this as a feature, so I'm asking: **How do I recover Markdown from a Stack Overflow data dump**?

---

(Thanks to Eric and to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), who pointed me at the data dump.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now available.

The records in `PostHistory` contain the raw markdown, while the records in `Posts` contain the cooked HTML from the most recent revision.

Answer (score 4):

> Can Markdown be recovered from the SO data dump?

Yes, but as with most translations the markdown may not match the original.  However, the HTML output would be the same, so there's no real impact.

From [SO podcast #80](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/podcast-80/) we learned:

> Stack Overflow user [William Shields](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus)
> has taken up Joel’s challenge to write
> a Markdown parser the right way — and
> produced an excellent series of
> articles about what he’s learned in
> the process: [one](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/jmd-markdown-and-brief-overview-of.html), [two](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/more-details-on-jmd-markdown-parsing.html), [three](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/markdown-musings-on-unintended.html), [four](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/markdown-headings-grief-and-unknown.html).
> It’s a perfect example of the type of
> learning that Stack Overflow itself is
> all about; kudos to William for
> sharing it!

William shares in those articles that one of the uses of his parser will be converting HTML into markdown.  You might contact him to see where he's at, and what other resources he is aware of.

However, conversion of markdown to HTML wouldn't be a bad topic to discuss on SO as well, so you might consider using that resource.

Answer (score 0):

It should be trivial to convert the two back and fourth by a simple replacement, `<b>` => `**` and `<i>` => `*`, etc.

Some PHP programs will do this for you, for instance [Markdownify](http://milianw.de/projects/markdownify/index.php).

Comment: trivial's not exactly the right word, there's a lot more to it than that...

Comment: Just use a regex...its easy `:P`

Comment: Or try jquery...

Comment: I would consider it trivial. Each element in markdown has a equivalent in HTML, which is what makes it such a great medium for interchange. The conversion may take *awhile* but the process itself isn't that difficult.

Comment: it might be trivial to make it work *most* of the time.  but there are edge cases where `markdownToHtml(htmlToMarkdown(str)) != str`.  For one example, `<b>un</b>broken` would not be properly converted to `**un**broken`, because (IIRC) the double-star in the middle of an unbroken word doesn't end the boldness.

Comment: There are some examples where I have to carefully craft the Markdown, and HTML, for it to come out like I want it to.

Comment: Technically, the html in the posts is markdown already...so the job is easy!

Comment: `<code>&#96;&#96;</code>`

Comment: Since several of you seem to disagree I'd be willing to convert it, but someone else will have to distribute it. Bandwidth is a very valuable commodity here.

Comment: @Ian - http://bitbucket.org/, http://codeplex.com, http://http://sourceforge.net/ amongst a few. If you don't want to setup an account, I can host in one of my repos.