# Record of answers to deleted questions

Tags: support, revisions-list

I wrote an answer to a question that has since been deleted. Is there any record of what I wrote?

If not, how can I download all the answers I've ever posted to Stack Overflow?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944119/ruby-methods-with/12944174#12944174

Comment: You can't get a list of your deleted posts. But if you have a link, then any 10k user can retrieve it for you.

Comment: Here's your answer: They're optional, makes no difference to how the code runs. 

Debate as to preference rages on

* http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/do_i_need_these_parentheses
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340624/do-you-leave-parentheses-in-or-out-in-ruby

Comment: You can ask the team (team@stackoverflow.com), but you better ask for something specific. If you ask for *every* answer you've posted, you're probably not going to get them. If it helps, this is the only deleted answer you've posted that has a score greater than 0.

Comment: Regarding downloading your answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14696/dont-wanna-be-a-digital-sharecropper-can-i-download-my-own-so-answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answers are only "soft-deleted", meaning they exist but are hidden from regular users.

Users with over 10k reputation, moderators, or SE employees can view Deleted questions and answers. In addition, you can view your own deleted answers if you can view the question, although this isn't the case since the question itself is deleted.

Moderators and SE employees can find deleted questions from your profile, but 10k users need to have a link to the question to see it.

Since you provided a link to the deleted question, I can find it and copy it here :)

> They're optional, makes no difference to how the code runs.
>
> Debate as to preference rages on
>
> - http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/do_i_need_these_parentheses
> - [Do you leave parentheses in or out in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340624/do-you-leave-parentheses-in-or-out-in-ruby)

There currently isn't any way for a user to get a list of their deleted items (other than asking a SE employee), however if you have the "Show Removed Posts" checked in your reputation page, you can probably find some of them.

Comment: All users can see their own deleted answers, as long as the question is still there.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Thanks, I updated my answer to include that info. I always forget that bit.